# React JS Renders Funny and Weird Fonts from Normal Text

Tags: reactjs

[image: Showing Weird fonts after rendering]

Hi guys,

I am building an website using react JS and came across this problem. I am fetching this data from API, there is normal text in the database, but after rendering it with react, I am getting these funny characters.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!!!

Comment: What do you have in response? Check in Network tab in Developer tools

Comment: @kiranvj I have status code 200 with response headers as content-type: text/html and content encoding gzip. If thats what you are after.

Comment: What do you see in response body? If the response body has the same chars, the issue is in backend and not in React